# Symbian Qt Development Linux

Tags: windows, linux, qt, ubuntu, symbian

I want to change to Ubuntu but I can't find a clear answer on if the latest Qt SDK for Linux will allow me to develop for Symbian (Like it does on windows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Symbian development using Linux](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/04/21/symbian-development-using-linux/).

In short, it is possible since the Qt 4.7 release. You'll need to download the S60 SDK and a patch, then set up your environment to use the cross-compiler, all of which is described in the above link.

The official docs for Qt 4.8 are here: [Installing Qt for the Symbian platform using Linux](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-symbian-linux.html), and have more information on things like building signed packages.